# Scroll down Chrome addon with virtual keyboard on mac

Tags: applescript, automator

I want to scroll down layout in chrome (or firefox) addon with automator mac.
Automator doesn't support scroll as i understand.
i've tried to use keybord maestro.
So i want't make a button on virtual keyboard and click it when i need to scroll.
What script i can use to scroll addon in chrome? i need to scroll addon, not a page.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5zwlx4li6xyw7bv/Scroll.png?dl=0

Comment: Please do not cross post the same question on multiple **Stack Exchange** sites. You posted this on **Ask Different** https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/430759/scroll-down-chrome-addon-with-virtual-keyboard-on-mac  -- Edit your original question appropriately in order to have it reopened.

Answer (score 0):

**Try to imitate click & drag action** from one screen position to other script position, like here:

```
my mouseDrag(100, 200, 499, 400, 1) -- EDIT here 2 positions and the delay

on mouseDrag(xDown, yDown, xUp, yUp, delayTime)
    -- delayTime because the drag may fail if the UI isn't fast enough without a delay. For what I do, .1 works.
    do shell script "/usr/bin/python <<END
from Quartz.CoreGraphics import CGEventCreateMouseEvent
from Quartz.CoreGraphics import CGEventCreate
from Quartz.CoreGraphics import CGEventPost
from Quartz.CoreGraphics import kCGEventLeftMouseDown
from Quartz.CoreGraphics import kCGEventLeftMouseUp
from Quartz.CoreGraphics import kCGMouseButtonLeft
from Quartz.CoreGraphics import kCGHIDEventTap
from Quartz.CoreGraphics import kCGEventLeftMouseDragged
import time

def mouseEvent(type, posx, posy):
  theEvent = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(None, type, (posx,posy), kCGMouseButtonLeft)
  CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, theEvent)
def mousemove(posx,posy):
  mouseEvent(kCGEventMouseMoved, posx,posy);
def mousedrag(posx,posy):
  mouseEvent(kCGEventLeftMouseDragged, posx,posy);
def mousedown(posxdown,posydown):
  mouseEvent(kCGEventLeftMouseDown, posxdown,posydown);
def mouseup(posxup,posyup):
  mouseEvent(kCGEventLeftMouseUp, posxup,posyup);

ourEvent = CGEventCreate(None);
mousedown(" & xDown & "," & yDown & ");
time.sleep(" & (delayTime as text) & "); mousedrag(" & xUp & "," & yUp & ");
time.sleep(" & (delayTime as text) & "); mouseup(" & xUp & "," & yUp & ");
END"
end mouseDrag
```